# How can I get same result with same seed set at random.shuffle()

Tags: python, math, random

I have the following code:

```
import random
SEED = 448

myList = [ 'list', 'elements', 'go', 'here' ]
random.seed(SEED)
random.shuffle(myList)  
print "RUN1: ", myList

random.seed(SEED)
random.shuffle(myList)  
print "RUN2: ", myList
```

Now I expect RUN1 and RUN2, produces the same result:

```
RUN1:  ['here', 'go', 'list', 'elements']
RUN2:  ['here', 'go', 'list', 'elements']
```

But it gives this instead.

```
RUN1:  ['here', 'go', 'list', 'elements']
RUN2:  ['elements', 'list', 'here', 'go']
```

How can I modify my code to get the result behavior as I expected?

Comment: You did reset the seed, but you didn't reset `myList` to the same initial state.  Note that `shuffle()` modifies the list _in-place_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just putting @Tim Peters' comment into an answer. You need to reset the list each time, since `random.shuffle` is destructive:

```
import random
SEED = 448

original_list = ['list', 'elements', 'go', 'here']

random.seed(SEED)
my_list = original_list[:]
random.shuffle(my_list)
print "RUN1: ", my_list

random.seed(SEED)
my_list = original_list[:]
random.shuffle(my_list)
print "RUN2: ", my_list

# Output:
# RUN1:  ['here', 'go', 'list', 'elements']
# RUN2:  ['here', 'go', 'list', 'elements']
```